# Replacement for Secunia/Flexera PSI

Tags: windows, security

Secunia/Flexera PSI is an application and system update monitor for Windows. In comparison to other similar programs, Secunia PSI is a

> security tool designed to detect vulnerable and out-dated programs and plug-ins which expose your PC to attacks

Other similar services, like FileHippo, merely monitor whether there exists an update for installed applications but do not evaluate its security impact. Using Secunia PSI allows me to decide whether to install an update **based on its criticality from the security point of view**. In accordance with the saying "if its not broken, do not update it" :-).

The problem is, that Secunia PSI is now **discontinued**. Is there a similar tool that gives application update advices based on a database of security vulnerabilities (like the National Vulnerability Database, https://nvd.nist.gov/)?

Answer (score 0):

Flexera still offers Software Vulnerability Manager for enterprises, but there's no longer a personal option - https://www.flexera.com/products/operations/software-vulnerability-management.html